# Pointer to member function syntax when declaring a template

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

This is what I try to achieve:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void whenEntering( const std::string& strState, 
                       T& t, 
                       void T::(*pMemberFunction)(void)) /// compilation fails here
    {
        t.(*pMemberFunction)(); // this line is only an example
    }
}
```

*It's for a kind of callback system for reacting to some events I receive.*

However Visual 2010 gives me the following compilation error:

```
    error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
```

I may be wrong with the pointer-to-member syntax... but I am also afraid that I may not define a template this way... do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `void (T::*pMemberFunction)(void)`

The other issue is probably just a typo in your example usage, but calling the member function uses `.*` as a single operator; you can't have a `(` in-between them, or even whitespace. I'm guessing that's a typo because it's almost the correct way to deal with the weird operator precedence that pointer-to-member operators have:

```
(t.*pMemberFunction)();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. In particular, the syntax for declaring a pointer to member function is `void (T::* pMemberFunction)(void)`:

Overall, this is how your code should look like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void whenEntering( const std::string& strState,
                       T& t,
                       void (T::* pMemberFunction)(void)
                               ) /// this fails
    {
        t.*pMemberFunction(); // this line is only an example
    }
};
```